# How can I make powershell read data from inputbox vb

Tags: vb.net, powershell

```bsh
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.VisualBasic
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
$ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::Ok
$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Information
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter an IP address', 'IP Address', "$env:ip")

$Resultip = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox
Start-Sleep -seconds 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKLM\system\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\"{d54ef5db-94f3-48c0-95b6-253d518a926f}"\ -name IPAddress $env:ip
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Add the Subnet Mask', 'Subnet Mask', "$env:subnet")
$Resultsubnet = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox
Set-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKLM\system\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\"{d54ef5db-94f3-48c0-95b6-253d518a926f}"\ -name Subnetmask $env:subnet
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Add the Gateway', 'Gateway', "$env:gateway")
$Resultgateway = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox
Set-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKLM\system\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\"{d54ef5db-94f3-48c0-95b6-253d518a926f}"\ -name Defaultgateway $env:gateway
```

After the VB popup I want this data to be inserted or read in ps line set itemproperty but I cannot figure it out :(

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You never capture the outcome of the popup as in `$theStuffTheUserEntered = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox(..)`. Furthermore, `$env:ip`, `$env:subnet` and `$env:gateway` are not standard environment variables..

Comment: oke any idea how I can edit it? or how to capture the data thanks

Comment: You need to assign the output from `[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox(...)` on line 5. Read @Theo's comment again, he's literally showing you how

Comment: I'm a student still figuring it out that's why I'm asking I understand I have to capture the data and integrate it but don't know how to do it

Comment: Furthermore, you should **always** check user input for validity, especially if your intention is to write to the registry.. please, at the very least add switch `-WhatIf` to the Set-ItemProperty cmdlet

Comment: oke thank you for your advice, I have tried it now it pop ups every input double.

Comment: Makes sense, because you call each popup twice.. please try and follow the lines of code you have. First concentrate on the code for the popups only and follow the answer already given. Once you get that logic in your head, carefully proceed with the results you have

Comment: Ok Theo it worked thanks a lot $resultip = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter an IP address', 'IP Address', "$env:ip")
$resultgateway = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Add the Gateway', 'Gateway', "$env:gateway")
$resultsubnet = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Add the Subnet Mask', 'Subnet Mask', "$env:subnet")

Comment: Great! Please click the checkmark icon next to [Mathias R. Jessen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64414638/9898643) to tick this question off as 'done'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 5-7 where you prompt the user for an ip address:

```
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter an IP address', 'IP Address', "$env:ip")

$Resultip = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox
```

... you never actually assign the output of the first statement to anything. Replace those two lines with:

```
$Resultip = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox('Enter an IP address', 'IP Address', "$env:ip")
```

Now `$Resultip` will hold a copy of the string input by the user. Repeat for `$Resultsubnet` and `$Resultgateway`